# Why the KeyEvent doesn't working though implemented KeyListener interface?

Tags: java, jpanel, keylistener, keyevent

In the `KeyDemo` class i implements `KeyListener` but i can't understand why the `KeyEvent`s doesn't working. I'm pressing key's but nothing is happening. This is only a short `Demo` class of a big class. Someone help me to solve this problem.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class KeyDemo extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    public KeyDemo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            System.out.println("moving up");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            robot.moveRight();
            robot.setMovingRight(true);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            System.out.println("stop moving up");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            robot.stopLeft();
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
        KeyDemo demo = new  KeyDemo();
        f.add(demo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a focus issue.

Try hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> to gain focus on the panel or calling

```
demo.requestFocus();
```

Comment: I've hit the `Tab`, added `demo.requestFocus()` but nothing is working. why? @Paco Abato

Comment: Thanks all. My problem has solved.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `KeyDemo` class does not have focus.

Anyway, these days, the recommended way to do this is with key bindings: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: I've set `KeyDemo` class `focusable true`. but it's not working. what's the problem occuring actullay?

Comment: I've set `KeyDemo` class `focusable true`. but it's not working. what's the problem occuring actullay? @ControlAltDel